# Replacing Windows Azure Cache with Redis Cache?

Tags: asp.net, azure, caching, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am currently using Windows Azure Cache for caching, however I would like to use Redis cache. I tried removing the Windows Azure Caching package from my project and added the Redis caching packages, and configured appropriately.

However this doesn't seem to work and gives me a lot of build errors because I believe it's still looking for the Windows Azure Cache.

How would I go about fixing this and successfully switching over to the Redis Cache?

Also Wondering should I delete this section from my Web.config file for my WebRole?

```
  <dataCacheClients>
    <dataCacheClient name="default">

  <!--To use the Windows Azure Cache Service, set identifier to be the endpoint of the cache cluster -->
  <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="testingabc.cache.windows.net" />
  <!--<localCache isEnabled="true" sync="TimeoutBased" objectCount="100000" ttlValue="300" />-->
  <!--Use this section to specify security settings for connecting to your cache. This section is not required if your cache is hosted on a role that is a part of your cloud service. -->
  <securityProperties mode="Message" sslEnabled="true">
    <messageSecurity authorizationInfo="MyAuthInfo" />
  </securityProperties>
</dataCacheClient>
```

Comment: You may want to add the description of those build errors here in your question.

Comment: Only to be expected? Redis isn't a drop in replacement for Windows Azure Cache. The packages don't implement the same API.

Comment: The Error is: "CloudServices64:Cannot find the file named 'approot\bin\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.caching\ClientPerfCounterInstaller.exe' for startup task Microsoft.WindowsAzure.caching\ClientPerfCounterInstaller.exe of myprojWebRole

Comment: @TimLovell-Smith How would I go about making the change then?

Answer (score 0):

For this particular error: `The Error is: "CloudServices64:Cannot find the file named 'approot\bin\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.caching\ClientPerfCounterInstaller.exe' for startup task Microsoft.WindowsAzure.caching\ClientPerfCounterInstaller.exe of myprojWebRole`, please try disabling in-role cache by going into caching tab of your web role project's properties:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might not be understanding some of what's required to switch to redis. The old Windows Azure Cache solution that you're using works by having the cache run on your worker/web roles as a Windows Azure 'Plugin'. (Then you access that cache using the Azure Caching client library.) There's no equivalent plugin for redis. To switch to redis you need to:

1) Stop using the Azure Caching client library and switch to e.g. StackExchange.Redis as client library - whatever redis library you use, it is a whole different API, you'll need to change your C# code that does cache operations.

2) Turn off the Plugin (which is that 'Enable Caching' checkbox), and remove any related startup tasks/artifacts fro your role definition. Then you won't be running a cache locally on your web/worker role any more.

Once you've properly uninstalled the plugin and client library you shouldn't see errors about ClientPerfCounterInstaller any more.

3) Separately provision an Azure Redis Cache to be your cache, (via portal, powershell etc) so that you have a cache to connect to, and configure your app with a connection string.

Comment: Thanks that was really insightful! Another question I had was in my web.config file for the WebRole I see this tag, should I take it out if I'm switching to Redis Cache --- I put the code in my description.

Comment: @chillax786 yes you can delete the entire dataCacheClient section from web.config